# Java - Binary Image Pixel Index

Tags: java, image-processing

How can I tell if a binary image that I am generating is 0-indexed or 1-indexed?

I have made a program which reads in an image, generates a binary image and performs some other functions on the image.  I would like to know, however, how to tell which 'index' the pixel values in the binary image are?

How is this done?

Is there a simple built-in function (such as `image.getRGB();`, for example) which can be called to determine this?

Comment: what is a 'binary image'? what classes or data structures are you using?

Comment: Binary as in a purely black and white image where pixels are either black or white.

Comment: When you "read in an image", how is it stored? That should answer your question "Is there a simple built-in function (such as image.getRGB();, for example)". Once you sort that out, create a small image manually, set one of the pixels to black and the rest white, and you can very quickly determine how the indexing is set up   e.g. by printing off the indices and values.

Comment: with 'binary image', I mean, is it an array or a `BufferedImage` or something else? Why don't you post a code fragment?

Comment: It is a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Do you mean "how do I determine the index of a pixel in the image" or "how do I determine if a given pixel is black or white"?

Comment: I mean the former, "how do I determine the index of a pixel in the image?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with 0- or 1-indexed, but here are some facts.

`BufferedImage` is a generic image, so pixels start at coordinate (0,0)

If you want an array to work on, coming from this image, the upper-left corner will be in index 0 (unless otherwise specified)

`image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), array, 0, image.getWidth());`

`BufferedImage` doesn't support 1 BPP images natively, but either via a *Packed* mode with a Colormodel, or a 2-index palette. I can't tell which one you have without examples.

Regardless of the internal format, the different getRGB() methods should always return one value per pixel, and one pixel per value. Note that the full-opacity value (0xFF000000, -16777216) will also be included in results.

eg.

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);

    image.setRGB(0, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    image.setRGB(1, 0, 0xFF000000);
    image.setRGB(0, 1, 0xFF000000);
    image.setRGB(1, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF);

    System.out.println(image.getRGB(0, 0));
    System.out.println(image.getRGB(1, 0));
    System.out.println(image.getRGB(0, 1));
    System.out.println(image.getRGB(1, 1));

    int[] array = image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth());
    System.out.println(array[0]); // at (0,0)
    System.out.println(array[1]); // at (1,0)
    System.out.println(array[16]); // at (0,1)
    System.out.println(array[17]); // at (1,1)
```